# How to link my first input box to another input box, which it has been in database

Tags: html, database, input, hyperlink

I want to link my input text to another input text, but it'll be planned like have been in databases,

ex : I want to input like "Acesulfame" in the first inputbox (Name Item) and then in the second inputbox it'll says "Sweeteners" (Sub. Category) and in the third inputbox it'll says "0001" (Code Oracle).

how should I do then?, this is only for an example.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="code_oracle">Code Oracle</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input name='code_oracle' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Code Oracle' required title='Code Revision Formula' id="code_oracle" value=""></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name_item">Name Item</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input name='name_item' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Nama Sample' required title='Name Sample' id="name_item" value=""></input>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="category">Sub. Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                 <input name='category' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Sub. Category' required title='Sub. Category' id="category" value=""></input>
            </div>
    </div>
```

My real code is in below.

```
<input name='kode_oracle' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Kode Oracle' required data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Kode Revisi Formula' id='kode_oracle'>
<input name='nama_item' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Nama Sederhana' required data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Nama Sederhana' id='nama_item' onkeyup='fill()'>
<input name='sub_kategori' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Sub. Kategori' required data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Sub. Kategori' id='sub_kategori'>
```

Can anyone help me?, I can't found the code anywhere, and I can't create a code to do that.

Comment: If you only use PHP you need a page refresh to update the other inputs. If you want it interactively you can use javascript. Then you either need to load the database in javascript or make an AJAX call to load the data from the server. From the code you provided it's not really clear what your intention is, maybe you can provide us with some more infromation?

Comment: The code is just a sample from my code is, I really confusing about this situation, I've been looking the code in anywhere and it's naught.

Comment: I've been try it on codepen.io same as you, and it's working, but when I'm try it to my code isn't work, did something happening?, I also use bootstrap, it because bootstrap or something else?, everyone help~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Get Data from database by AJAX call and in JSON format
2. Assign respone object to variable data
3. Use onkeyup function to autofill input boxes by Name value

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="code_oracle">Code Oracle</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input name='code_oracle' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Code Oracle' required title='Code Revision Formula' id="code_oracle" value=""></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name_item">Name Item</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input name='name_item' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Nama Sample' required title='Name Sample' id="name_item" value="" onkeyup="fill()"></input>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Sub. Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                 <input name='category' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Sub. Category' required title='Sub. Category' id="category" value=""></input>
            </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var data =[{
  "name":"Acesulfame",
  "sub":"Sweeteners",
  "code":"0001"
 },{
    "name":"XYZ",
  "sub":"abc",
  "code":"0002"
 },{
    "name":"AAA",
  "sub":"ZZZ",
  "code":"0003"
 }]

var fill =function(){

    var result = data.filter(function( obj ) {
     return obj.name == document.getElementById('name_item').value;
    });

    document.getElementById('category').value = result[0].sub;
    document.getElementById('code_oracle').value =result[0].code;

}
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aBrXod

Comment: I think this is have clear enough for me, but I have a problem about that code, it didn't work with PHP, can you tell me the JS should put where?, in first file or second file?, 'cause I have a two .php file, and it's two have been linked each other.

Comment: create on js file and have AJAX call and that onkeyup function and include it in the PHP files  ?> <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script> <?php

Comment: I've been put that code to my <script></script> in my first file .php, and it's not work yet,

I need some advice again, can you?

Comment: Did you try adding it in second file?

Comment: My second file .php is focusing on query for my first file .php, so it can't be placed there

Comment: I've been try it on codepen.io same as you, and it's working, but when I'm try it to my code isn't work, did something happening?, I also use bootstrap, it because bootstrap or something else?, everyone help~!

Comment: can you share your console log errors to debug easily?

Comment: I can't, I don't know how :'/

Comment: if you are using chrome , click Ctrl + Shift +J

Comment: I am using firefox, and have do the same as yours, and I don't know how console work for :'/

Comment: What's the point?, I don't know where to find all the errors on console :'/